# Undefined value document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem right here. i want to make a web service requestor using provider that i already make. the problem is i always getting undefined values for ID, Kab, and ID2. can someone help me fix the code in requestor?

this is the provider

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    array_push($result, array(
        'IDKabupaten' => $row['IDKabupaten'],
        'Kabupaten' => $row['Kabupaten'],
        'attribut' => array(
            0 => array(
                'IDProvinsi' => $row['IDProvinsi']
            )
        )
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('mytable' => $result));
?>
```

this is the requestor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/json2/wsp_coba2.php", function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result,function(i)
        {
            document.getElementById("DataKabupaten").innerHTML +="ID :" + result[i].IDKabupaten +"<br>Kab :" + result[i].Kabupaten 
            +"<br>ID2 :" + result[i].IDProvinsi + "<br><br>";
        });
    });
</script>
```

im getting

```
ID : undefined
Kab : undefined
ID2 : undefined
```

Comment: what does `console.log(result);`  return !?

Comment: it return my json object that i already make in provider

Comment: example data of it !?

Comment: `undefined`  is data getting of you wrong

Comment: it return this
Object { mytable: (3) […] }
mytable: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]​​
0: Object { IDKabupaten: "3301", Kabupaten: "CILACAP", attribut: (1) […] }
1: Object { IDKabupaten: "3302", Kabupaten: "BANYUMAS", attribut: (1) […] }
2: Object { IDKabupaten: "3303", Kabupaten: "PURBALINGGA", attribut: (1) […] }​​
length: 3
<prototype>: Array []
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: result.mytable !??  
`$.each(result.mytable,function(i)`

Comment: {
    "mytable": [
        {
            "IDKabupaten": "3301",
            "Kabupaten": "CILACAP",
            "attribut": [
                {
                    "IDProvinsi": "33"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "IDKabupaten": "3302",
            "Kabupaten": "BANYUMAS",
            "attribut": [
                {
                    "IDProvinsi": "33"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: you miss property `mytable` of `result`

Comment: @Xupitan when i add mytable in result its giving me error

Comment: i've just created example for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const result = { "mytable": [ { "IDKabupaten": "3301", "Kabupaten": "CILACAP", "attribut": [ { "IDProvinsi": "33" } ] }, { "IDKabupaten": "3302", "Kabupaten": "BANYUMAS", "attribut": [ { "IDProvinsi": "33" } ] } ] };
$.each(result.mytable,function(i) {
  console.log(result.mytable[i].IDKabupaten);
  $.each(result.mytable[i].attribut, function (j) {
    console.log(result.mytable[i].attribut[j].IDProvinsi)  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can check it

Comment: your code does work but when i try to add result.mytable[i].IDProvinsi in console.log it say undefined

Comment: how can i use result.attribut in that case?

Comment: @vincent For IDProvinsi, it would be `result.mytable[i].actribut[0].IDProvinsi`

Comment: @vincent you can $.each it

Comment: ahhh you're right xupitan & carsten, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$.each(result,function(i)
        {
            document.getElementById("DataKabupaten").innerHTML +="ID :" + result[i].IDKabupaten +"<br>Kab :" + result[i].Kabupaten 
            +"<br>ID2 :" + result[i].IDProvinsi + "<br><br>";
        });
result.forEach((singleResult, index) => {
// and then do your thing here. I don't use jquery but I took a quick look at their docs and your loop doesn't look right. This is the same function that jquery is calling under the hood.
})
```

Delete your code... I only left it in there so you could compare.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).